# How to check any services exists by Ansible?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

I want to check the service exists in the terminal host.

So, I just did the playbook as below.

```
---

- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes
  vars:
    servicename:
  tasks:

  - name: Check if Service Exists
    stat: 'path=/etc/init.d/{{ servicename }}'
    register: servicestatus
    with_items: '{{ servicename }}'

  - name: Show service service status
    debug:
      msg: '{{ servicename }} is exists.'
    with_items: '{{ servicename }}'
    when: servicestatus.stat.exists
```

Then, I try to execute this playbook to my host that was running Nginx already as below.

```
ansible-playbook cheknginxservice.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts -e 'host=hostname' -e 'servicename=nginx'
```

And I got the error like this.

```
 FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'servicestatus.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (servicestatus.stat.exists): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/centos/cheknginxservice.yml': line 13, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    with_items: '{{ servicename }}'\n  - name: Show service servicestatus\n    ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/centos/cheknginxservice.retry
```

So, I think the problem is about stat module when using the condition involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `with_items`? You plan to pass multiple services? It matters because the results will be a list if you use `with_items`. Just remove `with_items` and it will work. If you want to pass multiple services, then you have to loop through `with_items` and use `item` instead of `servicename`.

```
  - name: Check if Service Exists
    stat: 'path=/etc/init.d/{{ servicename }}'
    register: servicestatus

  - name: Show service service status
    debug:
      msg: '{{ servicename }} is exists.'
    when: servicestatus.stat.exists
```

There is no native way in Ansible to check the status of a service. You can use the `shell` module. Notice I used `sudo`. Your case may be different.

```
  - name: check for service status
    shell: sudo service {{ servicename }} status
    ignore_errors: true
    register: servicestatus

  - name: Show service service status
    debug:
      msg: '{{ servicename }} exists.'
    when: servicestatus.rc | int == 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. I just don't know what exactly "with_items" means. So, I use it many time in previously work.

Comment: I just try removed the nginx service by using command " apt-get remove nginx " in the host terminal. But the file "nginx" in /etc/init.d is still exists. So, my task still got output that is exists. Are there some another way to check the service exists via Ansible? Thanks.